# How to extract file path from text file if present or enter filepath manually if not present in text file using C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file with information:

```
Template
PUC C# Assignment.
Path=E:\Project_PU.xlsx
Path=
EMailId=abc@xyz.com; def@xyz.com; ghi@xyz.com
```

I am parsing the text file using C# and looking for "Path=" and extract the path after "=" and open it for further operation. If "Path=" has no path mentioned then it should ask user to enter the path manually on console window. Can anyone please help me where I am going wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string file = "E:\\Project_PU.txt";
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
                String lines = sr.ReadToEnd();  

                int x = lines.IndexOf('=');
                int y = lines.IndexOf('_');
                string x = lines.Substring(x + 1, y - x);


                string mail = File.ReadAllLines(file).FirstOrDefault(line => line.StartsWith("EmailId="));
                string sString = mail;
                string[] sLines = sString.Split(new string[] { "EmailId=", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                Excel.Application xlApp;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                Excel.Range range;

                long rowCount;
                long rw = 0;
                long cl = 0;

                xlApp = new Excel.Application();

                string path = "";
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();


                if (File.Exists(path))
                {

                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: How to extract file path from the text file. In the code I have explicitly mentioned the path. But, I have to extract the path from text file after "Path="

Comment: You already have code that will get the email value from the file based on a line starting with `Email=`. Why not just do that for the `Path=`?

Comment: Also, FWIW, the code you present does not look like it will compile. You can't have two variables with the same name (`x`). Also, this line seems pointless: `string sString = mail;` since you could just use `mail` instead.

Comment: @Rufus that mail ids have to be extracted to send email. I am only interested in file path for now. How to extract the path from text file?

Comment: it's not the best but you could use the same code and replace `Email=` with `Path=`

Comment: Does the file really have multiple lines that begin with `Path=`?

Comment: @Rufus yes. If the path is present after Path=, it has to extract from the text file itself, if path is not present after Path=, then it should ask the user to enter the path manually on the console window

Comment: My question is, what if there are multiple lines that begin with `Path=` (as your example shows)? Do you pick the first one? The last one? The first one with a valid path?

Comment: @Rufus, we pick the first one. If the path is not present in the first one, it will look in the second one and if the path is not present after Path=, then user should manually enter the path on console window

Comment: ok. updated answer to use the first line that begins with `Path=` and which is followed by a valid file path, otherwise prompt the user.

Comment: @Rufus, it will keep on checking for Path= and if path is present then it will extract the path and open the file. If in the last occurence of Path= there is no path mentioned, then it should prompt the user to enter the path

Comment: @Rufus thank you so much for your help.
Now, I have one more doubt. What if the text file contains the data in the same line, then how to extract the file path? Now we, have data in every line so we are checking every line. What if the text file now has information like :
Template PUC C# Assignment.Path=E:\Project_PU.xlsxPath= EMailId=abc@xyz.com; def@xyz.com; ghi@xyz.com

Comment: Then you'd have to parse it differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is similar to what you're already doing with the email: read the file lines into an array, find the first one that starts with `Path=` and contains a valid file path, and get the text after the `=` sign. If the file doesn't contain `Path=`, or there is no text after the `=` sign, or the text after the `=` sign isn't a valid file, then prompt the user for the path:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = "E:\\Project_PU.txt";

    // This will hold the path value
    string path = null;

    // Get all the file lines into an array
    string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    // Find all the lines that begin with 'Path='
    List<string> pathLines = fileLines.Where(l => l.StartsWith("Path=")).ToList();

    // If we found any lines, get the first one that has a valid path
    if (pathLines != null && pathLines.Any())
    {
        // Get the first entry that begins with 'Path=' and ends with a valid file path
        path = pathLines
            .FirstOrDefault(l => File.Exists(l.Substring(l.IndexOf("=") + 1)));

        if (path != null) path = path.Substring(path.IndexOf("=") + 1);
    }

    // If there was no path specified, then prompt the user to enter one
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the path: ");
        path = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If you have any concerns about case-sensitivity (like if the entry in the file might be `path=`), then you could change the line above that reads the file line to this instead:

```
// Find the first line that starts with 'Path='
string pathLine = fileLines.FirstOrDefault(l => 
    l.IndexOf("Path=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
```

Note that you can continue to use `fileLines` for your other checks, like `Email=`.